# Changing Edit Sketch Symbology in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, editing, arcgis-pro

I am trying to change the sketch symbology for vertices in ArcGIS Pro 1.3. I know you can [change the symbol from the default in ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/changing-the-edit-sketch-vertex-and-segment-symbols.htm). I was wondering if there was the equivalent for Pro.

Below is the place to edit sketch symbology in ArcMap.

[image: Edit Sketch Symbology in ArcMap 10.3.1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find no place to change the sketch symbology for vertices in ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1 either.  If it were present I would expect to find it on the Editing tab of the Options dialog.

[image]

Consequently, I think you should submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas) and post a link to it within a self-answer to this question.